# Setting env variables after build in react without .env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, pm2

I am trying to set env variables from pm2 after I build my react project using

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_URL_SECRET_SIGNING_KEY=ABC pm2 restart server.js --update-env
```

But the build is not identifying any env variables and I'm getting env variables as undefined.

however the node is consoling all the variables on the project start point when i console them.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv gets used 4M times per week.  Maybe give that a shot.

Comment: without using .env file?

Comment: With the .env 
`import {} from 'dotenv/config'`
`process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_URL_SECRET_SIGNING_KEY`